# When does Google consider linking as bad-neighborhood / link scheme/ spamming etc.?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, links, backlinks

I cannot understand this concept, please give me some clarity on this.

If I link to a site, and it links to me, then is it a link scheme ?

I see many seo companies link to their other sites, from their sites, and they rank well.

Is it ok to exchange links between the sites I have built ?

and moreover, is it ok to give a link to my w3c html validation page, since it gives back a 'follow' link to me ? the anchor text is my domain name.

Answer (score 2):

Its primarily depends on the number of OBL (follow link) from the site you are getting inbound links and anchor text. If you are getting a link back from a site that gives (follow) link back to thousands other sites and has over-optimized anchor text for the links, the chances are that your website will get a negative effect.

For example:

> View our rankings of the **top SEO companies** of 2013

Here '**top SEO companies**' is a keyword. If we use it as anchor text for some SEO website, that is over-optimized anchor text. Naked URL, non descriptive anchor text are safe.

Linking other own site is okay, if they have unique C-Block IP Addresses, But don't over do it.

Comment: Any out bound link (OBL) can be of two type 'follow' and 'nofollow'. Follow link is default, if nothing is mentioned. Check the example below for nofollow link.
`<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.example.com/">`

Comment: oh, sorry, I misunderstood the phrase haha!

Comment: so, for the case of w3 validator, it is safe, then ? anchor text is my domain name and it does not contain rel="nofollow". But that domain has millions of links to other sites.

Comment: I guess in w3 validator case you are the one to put the icon on your site that link back to validation page! if it is so, you can make it nofollow to preserve your website's link juice